# Usage of “any person” and “each person.”

Tags: any

There are three people, and each person has three pencils. Then, could I say “any person has nine pencils”?

Comment: That is liable to be interpreted, if at all, as meaning each has nine pencils. They have nine pencils in total, is that what you are trying to convey.

Comment: @mdewey They have nine pencils in total.

Comment: @user142405 No you can't if you want to be correctly understood. You mean that **Each person has three pencils.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is not clear and would not be interpreted the way you want by native speakers.

We don't use *any* in the way you're using it here.  As other commenters have said, we would say **each** person has three pencils.  *Any* means "one or another chosen at random", so the only way to use it correctly in this case is to say something like "Any person you choose has three pencils."

We usually use *any* in negative senses, like "I don't see any person with four pencils", or questions, like "Is there any person who has two pencils?"  As you can see, it always refers to *one* person, so you can't say "any of them have nine pencils".

Reference: [Some/any](http://esl.fis.edu/grammar/rules/some.htm)